# Empty cleaned_data

Tags: django, inline-formset

I am not understanding why this is happening.  I have apply the exact same code to other inline formsets but this specific inline formset is not saving any of my changes.  I found that within my form "AtLeastOneFull" that form.cleaned_data is always empty despite that I have data.

The webpage displays the contents of model 'Access' correctly, but once I click submit, it registers as invalid because I have no data regardless of the changes I make to the inline form's data on the web page.

**forms:**

```
class AtLeastOneFull(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        count = 0
        for form in self.forms:
            try:
                if form.cleaned_data and not form.cleaned_data.get('access_rights', ACCESS_CHOICES[0][0]):
                    count += 1
                    assert False
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        if count < 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError('You must have at least one full access user')

class UserAccessForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Access
    def clean(self):
       cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
       # Check 1: Must have valid user.
       # To Be Developed
       return cleaned_data
```

**models:**

```
class Portfolio (models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True) #Street address, P.O. box, company name, c/o
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True) #Apartment, suite, unit, building, floor, etc.
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.nickname)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

# Property Expansion
class Access (models.Model):
    portfolio_id = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    access_rights = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=ACCESS_CHOICES)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s: %s' % (self.portfolio_id, self.user_id)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['portfolio_id', 'user_id']
        unique_together = ("portfolio_id", "user_id")
```

**view:**

```
cPortfolio = Portfolio.objects.get(nickname=pNickname)
AccessFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Portfolio,
                                      Access,
                                      form=UserAccessForm,
                                      formset=AtLeastOneFull,
                                      extra=1,
                                      can_delete=False)
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'access_apply' in request.POST:
        cAccessFormSet = AccessFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=cPortfolio)
        if cAccessFormSet.is_valid():
            testResults  = cAccessFormSet.save(commit=False)
            for form in testResults:
                form.save()
cAccessFormSet = AccessFormSet(instance=cPortfolio)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely it's not as simple as removing the `assert False` statement in `AtLeastOneFull.clean`?

Also, why is `UserAccessForm.clean` querying `User`s by `"Username"`, when the model field is actually `user_id`?

Comment: The "assert False" is something I put in to know when my if statement evaluates as true. That never happens. My debugging reveiled that cleaned_data is always empty.

The username is something else I am working on and have not had the time to debug because of this other issue.  I will remove it so that it does not confuse others.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the clean function of the form.  The # To Be Developed was inserted to shorten the code for this question, but the real code had an issue that prevented data from being returned.

```
class UserAccessForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Access
    def clean(self):
       cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
       # Check 1: Must have valid user.
       # To Be Developed
       return cleaned_data
```